# Mouse Listener Interface and painting

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, paint, bufferedimage

I am trying to implement a graphics modelling tool.

[image: Graphics modelling]

On a mouse click a red vertex is generated. When mouse is dragged from one vertex to another, a line should be drawn. This is what I would like to achieve. But my code does not effectively do it. Following is my code and problem

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NewClass extends JPanel {
    Point source,dest;
    BufferedImage image;
    Graphics2D imageGraphics;
    NewClass(){
    image= new BufferedImage(400,400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    imageGraphics=image.createGraphics();
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
                Point p=e.getPoint();
                paintPoint(p);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
                source=e.getPoint();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
            if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){                  
                    dest=e.getPoint();
                    paintLine();
            }
        }    
    });
}
   public void paintPoint(Point r){
    imageGraphics.setColor(Color.red);
    imageGraphics.fillOval(r.x,r.y,5,5);
    repaint();
}
public void paintLine(){
    imageGraphics.setColor(Color.black);
    imageGraphics.drawLine(source.x,source.y,dest.x,dest.y);
    repaint();
}
}
```

However the problem I am facing is, when a mouseClickedEvent is generated, it generates pressed and released as well. Especially when more than three vertices are used, wrong lines are generated.

I want the line to be drawn only when pressed on a vertex, moved to the next vertex and then released there.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: this idea is wrong, a.m. way isn't proper (JAva6/7) for Painting in Swing

Comment: @mKorbel, what does `a.m.` means ?

Comment: @Sage a.m. == above mentioned (is legal blablabla)

Comment: muah ha ha ha ha ha :) :)

Comment: @mKorbel I do not know why the above is wrong. I observed it is slow. Why is it wrong? Tia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `mouseReleased` check the location of the release, if it is the same as your `source` you have a click not a drag. You can also get rid of the `mouseClicked` completely using this method

Answer (score 1):

You can simply override `mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)`, it's made for your usage.

Comment: That was my first thought but the function was being called for every pixel on the drag path, slowing down my program